# Why do C# and VB projects have a different manifest resource structures?

Tags: c#, vb.net, resources, manifest, converters

My project is a C# NET Framework 4.8 web app that utilizes a Resources folder (with files built as Embedded Resources) to fetch templates at runtime.

Recently I converted it from VB to C# using a very nice [Code Converter](https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter).  While it worked fine, now it seems the structure of the manifest resources has changed, as shown by Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().

For example, what used to be **App.IssueNotification.html** is now listed as **App.Resources.EmailTemplates.IssueNotification.html** .. matching the folder structure in the solution, but forcing me to make changes.

My questions are

1. What is this VB/C# difference actually called? Is there documentation?
2. Is there a setting or flag to use the "flatten" resource names like VB does so I don't need to update my code?

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I'd recommend comparing the vbproj file from before with the csproj file from after, and see how they include the resources.  As long as they don't involve `My`, I would expect you to be able to massage the project files to get the same behavior with both compilers.  Note that there are things you can do with the project files by hand that aren't accessible through the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vb library inside C# projects, is not an option for you to do it so?, this way you would not need to convert the project you can just easily access to it as an any .dll (library)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I think it would require more code changes than the simple changes in the resource file to make it work with c#

Comment: The project is already converted and I've updated most of my resource names, so it works with the fully-qualified C# names.  Mostly I was asking from curiosity, because this difference between C# and VB does not seem to be well documented.

Comment: I see, yes if that is the case you are absolutly right U_U